# What does the term 'Facet' in Seaborn FacetGrid imply?

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, seaborn, python-3.x

I am a newbie to data science. I have a very basic understanding of Seaborn. My understanding is that it is used to plot grids. That said, I intend to have a better understanding of '**FacetGrid**' and the term '**facet**'.

> FacetGrid is a multi-plot grid for plotting conditional relationships.
>   FacetGrid object takes a DataFrame as input and the names of the
>   variables that will form the row, column, or hue dimensions of the
>   grid. The variables should be categorical and the data at each level
>   of the variable will be used for a facet along that axis.

The confusion is in the line 'the data at each level of the variable will be used for a **facet** along that axis'. Here, what does it mean by facet?

I am adding a code example where FacetGrid is used(Here FacetGrid is used to plot a 2D scatter plot):

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.FacetGrid(haberman, hue ='Survival Status', size = 8) \
.map(plt.scatter, 'Age of Patient', 'Positive Axillary Nodes') \
.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

Can someone give a better explanation for a better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the facetGrid documentation :

> This class maps a dataset onto multiple axes arrayed in a grid of rows and columns that correspond to levels of variables in the dataset. The plots it produces are often called “lattice”, “trellis”, or “small-multiple” graphics.

Here levels mean  « categories ». The main goal is to not display the full set of data, but multiple subsets of data that fit conditions on categorical variables.

Definition of facet found [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/facet) :

> facet : a particular aspect or feature of something.

In the following example, the vertical axis (column of graphs) represents the facet/feature/attribute Smoker/Not-Smoker and the horizontal axis (line of graphs) represents the attribute Time. So each graph is the conditional AND between the two attributes :

- Smoker AND Lunch
- Smoker AND Dinner
- Not Smoker AND Lunch
- Not Smoker AND Dinner

[image]
<sub>(source: [pydata.org](https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/seaborn-FacetGrid-2.png))</sub>